# Webdriver/Java/Xpath: How can I click the second "Login" link

Tags: java, xpath, selenium, webdriver

How can I use an xpath expression to tell Selenium Webdriver to click the second "Login" link on a page?

OR:

How can I convert this to an absolute xpath

(//input[@name='commit'])[2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the webpage in Chrome, Inspect the element, right click on the highlighted node and click Copy XPath.

It should look something like:

```
//a[text()="Login"]
```

Comment: I get this, but I think I need to convert it to an absolute xpath?: (//input[@name='commit'])[2]

Comment: @JennyKowalski: Absolute XPath? It selects a single element.

Answer (score 0):

//input[2] will show ALL "input" element that are the 2nd "input" of its parent
eg:

```html
<div>
 <h1></h1>
 <input> this one is not 2nd input child</input>
</div>
<div2>
 <h1></h1>
 <input> this one is not 2nd input child</input>
 <input> this one is 2nd input child</input>
</div2>
```

---

To get the 2nd one in the order of element in the document, use "following"

Following: Selects everything in the document after the closing tag of the current node
Suppose "header" is the tag right before 2 "input" tags, so the xpath for the 2nd specified input tag should be

//head/following::input[@name='commit'][2]